# function inside react is not returning what it should

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

There are two kinds of Images that I have imported ( `IMG` and `IMG2` ). IMG suppose to be displayed when the viewport width is less than 600px and the other one would be displayed if the viewport is bigger or equal to 600px. So I added a function to check the viewport width then it returns one of these two images, but the problem is that it's only returning the first that I put in the function, which is the `IMG`. even when viewport width becomes bigger than 600px it's still displaying IMG instead of IMG2. Note: ***I can solve this by only using media queries and setting display to none but I would like to know how to do it with react.***

**Link to all my code in Github:** https://github.com/IssamAth/PerfumeProduct.com

```
import IMG from '../../assets/image-product-mobile.jpg'
import IMG2 from '../../assets/image-product-desktop.jpg'

const ProductImage = () => {
  function displayImage(){
    let vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);
    console.log(vw);
    if(vw < 600) {
     console.log(vw + "is smaller than 600");
     return (<img src={IMG} alt="" />);
    } else {
     console.log(vw + "is bigger than 600");
     return (<img src={IMG2} alt="" />);
    }
}
  return (
    <div className='container-img'>
      {displayImage()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductImage
```

```
.container-img img {
    height: 15rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0.8rem 0.8rem 0 0;
}

.container-img {
   
}

 /* -----------------for bigger phones------------------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 390px) {
    .container-img img {
        height: 20rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to call `displayImage` in a useEffect, maybe by then the browser has rendered and the values are valid

Comment: if the vieport is onload bigger than 600, does it display img2?

Comment: @alextrastero I tried, but I don't think I know how to do it. It's been awhile since I have used react

Comment: @Apostolos no it does not it keeps displaying only the IMG and not the IMG2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with React, you going to want to attach to the documents resize event.

Below is a simple example, that changes text & background color when resizing.

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const getWidth = () => document.documentElement.clientWidth;

const ResizeCheck = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(getWidth());
  useEffect(() => {
    const resize = () => setWidth(getWidth());
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
  }, []);
  return <div>{
    width >= 600 
      ? <div
        style={{backgroundColor: 'pink'}}
      >Greater than equal to 600</div>
      : <div style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>Less than 600</div>
    }
  </div>;
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#mount'));
root.render(<ResizeCheck/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this right now !